# use local typeface in vue-cli 3

Tags: vue.js, font-face, vue-cli

I want to import an local typeface into my vue-cli 3 project.

The .woff and .woff3 files are in src/assets/typo and I include them in src/scss/_typo.scss:
[image]

My _typo.scss looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HKGrotesk';
  src:  url('@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'HKGrotesk';
  src:  url('@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Medium.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: medium;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'HKGrotesk';
  src:  url('@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And this is my vue.config to use the colors and typeface globally:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/scss/_colors.scss";
          @import "@/scss/_typo.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

When I run my project I got the following error message:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Bold.woff' in '/Users/robin/Documents/Code/2018/iamrobin-portfolio/src'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been searching all over for an answer and can't get it to work. For me, I use the straight '/assets/typo/font.woff' path in my url. It compiles, but it doesn't show up in the browser

Comment: the reason that `'/assets/typo/...'` doesn't work is that it can't find the files. The files need to be relative to the `scss` file. Webpack will replace with the correct asset depending on whether it is running in dev or compiled for build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  `~@/assets/...`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HKGrotesk';
  src:  url('~@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('~@/assets/typo/HKGrotesk-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this helps at this stage but I had the same issue and resolved it by using relative paths (i.e. `../assets/fonts/myfont.woff`) rather than using the root wildcard (i.e. `@/assets/fonts/myfont.woff` or `@~/assets/fonts/myfont.woff`).

Hope it helps you!

Comment: For me, if I use relative path like '../assets/font/myfont.woff' I get a module error, not found. If I use just plain '/assets/fonts/myfont.woff' it compiles fine, but the font doesn't show up in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

With vue-cli 3, you have Webpack 4 and default loaders working for you, so you don't need to configure any loader for such a task. The only thing you'll have to do is create a `main.scss` file in your scss folder. In that file, import your `_color.scss` and `_typo.scss`. Then, in your `main.js` import your main style file like `import './stylus/main.scss';`. With that, you should be good to go. Just use your font in your css like `body {font-family: "HKGrotesk", sans-serif;}`, for instance. Don't forget to remove your css loader from `vue.config` to not interfere with webpack's default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, I wished it was referenced in vue cli github issues :) Fixed by forcing myself to use relative paths, but this sucks really.